# Cant find Adwords api v201809

Tags: google-api, nuget

installed api package version 24.2.0 via nuget in visual studio, still does not find api version v201809

get-package doesn't show any conflicting packages, so im not sure why this isnt showing up when I try to include it.

Answer (score 0):

```
use nuget to remove package (uninstall-package google.adwords)
manually look at and remove references
check project settings and make sure framework target > 4.5.2
install package (install-package google.adwords)
```